# Возможно ли не обособлять вводное слово, сославшись на то, что это союз?

Tags: союзы, вводные-слова

Возьмем, к примеру, союз / вводное слово ***значит*** в начале предложения. Можно ли писать:

> Дождь пошел. Это плохо. Значит я достаю зонт.

вместо

> Дождь пошел. Это плохо. Значит, я достаю зонт.

По итогам дискуссии, вынужден немного детализировать этот вопрос.

Вот есть у нас 3 пары предложений:

> 1. Дождь пошел. Значит, я достаю зонт.

> 2. Дождь пошел. Так что я достаю зонт.

> 3. Дождь пошел. Поэтому я достаю зонт.

Очевидно, что предложения синонимичны и функции всех слов в них одинаковые.

Однако, в согласии с синтаксической теорией, синтаксические функции этих слов не просто различные, а строго различные. Мы даже не имеем права сказать, что они одинаковые!

> 1. Дождь пошел. Значит, я достаю зонт (вводное слово).

> 2. Дождь пошел. Так что я достаю зонт (союз).

> 3. Дождь пошел. Поэтому я достаю зонт (обстоятельство причины).

Почему нельзя сказать, что все трое у нас - союзы?

Answer (score 2):

1. Максимально просто и понятно ответить на этот вопрос нам поможет **Розенталь**: § 25. Вводные слова и словосочетания, пункт 9 (12)
   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Также материал можно посмотреть в **Справочнике по пунктуации** http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_220

2. О чем там говорится. У слова «значит»  можно выделить **три основные функции:**  (1) вводное слово (обособляется); (2) слово-связка между подлежащим и сказуемым (ставится тире); (3) глагол, близкий по смыслу к глаголу «означает»  в  роли сказуемого (нет знаков).

Примеры.  (1) *Так, **значит**, вы сегодня не можете прийти?*  (2) *Бороться — **значит** победить.* (3) *Человек **значит** неизмеримо больше, чем принято думать о нём думать.*

3. **А как же союз?**  Иногда его так называют, но это **неточное определение**. В СПП слово «значит» может входить в составной союз в качестве **структурного элемента** «если…значит»;  в БСП  также  может являться структурным элементом, обозначая причинно-следственную связь между частями предложения. Но в обоих случаях оно **сохраняет статус вводного слова**, то есть **обособляется** запятыми.

Примеры. *Если наступит весна, **значит**, будет тепло* (СПП). *Прозвенел звонок, **значит,** урок кончился (БСП).*

4. Слово «значит» может находиться **в начале предложения,** если нужно обозначить причинно-следственную связь между отдельными  предложениями, но его функция структурного элемента остается прежней: оно **обособляется как вводное слово**.  Такое понимание полностью соответствует теории современного синтаксиса.

Пример: *Денег у меня чуть больше рубля. **Значит,** за рубль переваливать нельзя.*

5. Тогда получаем: *Дождь пошел. Это плохо. **Значит,**  я достаю зонт.*

А лучше так: *Дождь пошел. Это плохо. **Значит**,  придется достать зонт.*

Comment: Плюс, конечно, ставлю, но правильный ответ думаю дать сам. Придётся немного поразбираться.

Comment: Плюс за потраченное время, ведь вы считаете мой  ответ неправильным, не так ли?  Спасибо!  Тогда я тоже поставлю вам плюс за вопрос. А также желаю вас успеха в поисках истины. Жаль только, что никто еще не хочет нам в этом  помочь.

Comment: Может и правильный, надо ведь сначала разобраться в теме вводных слов и союзов, а потом судить ;) Пока вопросов больше чем ответов.

Comment: Конечно, разобраться нужно, тема непростая. Но в ваших словах есть некая определенность, высказанная заранее: "но правильный ответ думаю дать сам". Мне кажется, что из этого однозначно следует, что полученный  ответ вы считаете неправильным. По крайней мере, я так это слышу.

Comment: Да, правильный в том смысле, что проясняет недовысказанные, но подразумеваемые вопросы. Ваш ответ в этом смысле не многое проясняет для меня, хотя он, наверняка, правильный. К примеру, вместо Розенталя я нашел отличную брошюру. Но и её недостаточно. Вот есть 3 одинаковых пары предложений: Дождь пошел. Поэтому я достаю зонт. (обстоятельство причины). Дождь пошел. Так что я достаю зонт. (союз). Дождь пошел. Значит я достаю зонт (вводное слово). Вы можете пояснить в своем ответе почему в 3-х одинаковых парах предложений, синтаксичские функции слов различаются? (обстоятельство/союз/вводное слово).

Comment: Могу ли я пояснить…  Могу, но не вижу в этом смысла.  Вы предлагаете предложения придуманные, не живые, не настоящие, а я не люблю с такими работать.  Вы ошибаетесь при их составлении и некорректно оцениваете  отношения между ними.  Наверное, это хорошо, что вы думаете, задаете вопросы, но у вас недостаточная база знаний, чтобы разобраться в них.  Вам нужно взять хорошую книгу по современному синтаксису и очень внимательно ее изучить от начала до конца.  Тогда вы, возможно, сделаете какие-то интересные открытия.

Comment: Я  на вашем месте начала бы с анализа слов, а не предложений. «Поэтому» (по этой причине) и «так что» (значение следствия)  по смыслу похожи, но  вводное слово «значит» – это вывод, а не следствие. А грамматика? Почему «поэтому»  –  это наречие, а «так что»  – союз? Это тоже интересные  вопросы. Подумайте сами, дайте свой ответ (да и на форуме мы эту тему, кажется,  обсуждали).  И когда это станет понятным, то и ваши предложения вы, возможно, не будете считать одинаковыми, сформулируете их по-другому, то есть сами разберетесь с ними.

Comment: Если бы все было так просто- взял и прочитал книгу. Проще самому написать книгу, чем найти что-то целостное, без дыр, противоречий и рецептов с неба.

Comment: А вы не ищите легких путей,  получение хороших знаний требует усилий. Для начала исправьте предложение, которое у вас неправильно составлено: Дождь пошел. Значит, я достаю зонт (вводное слово). Почему оно некорректно, как его можно исправить? Здесь уже не знания нужны, а чувство языка и умение мыслить. Если справитесь с такой задачей, тогда и  ставьте пред собой более сложные.

Comment: Для начала это не предложение, а два предложения. И какое из этих двух вы считаете некорректным?

Comment: Оба, в совокупности как бы. Они же описывают конкретную ситуацию, а ситуация мне представляется неясной.  К тому же эта ситуация отлична от изображенной ранее. Там у нас следствие, а вводное слово имеет значение вывода. Ваш персонаж сам за собой наблюдает и делает выводы?

Comment: Отлична, да. Она проще. Вот с простого и начинаем. Теперь насчет ситуации в целом . Вам ведь понятны предложения из справочника по союзам: "Ты сердишься, значит ты неправ." и "Все идут в эту сторону, значит там и клюква растет". К ним у вас нет вопросов? Если нет, то просто разделяем эти предложения пополам. Что изменилось? - ничего. Только синтаксис теперь начинает нам "втирать", что "значит" уже не союз, а вводное слово.

Comment: Ладно, вы неисправимы. Закончим наш диалог на моем видении вашего предложения.  «Дождь пошел. Значит, я достаю зонт». Вероятно, вы просматриваете запись и думаете: Вот я открываю сумку, интересно, зачем это? Ах да, дождь пошел, значит, я достаю зонт. Вы комментируете свои действия, которые видите как бы со стороны. Уже в своем ответе я предлагала вам исправить предложение: «Дождь пошел. Значит, придется достать зонт». Теперь оно составлено верно, вы  делаете вывод о своих предстоящих действиях. Но вам мой ответ не понравился, вы его или не читали вовсе, или читали невнимательно.

Comment: (Невнимательность – это вообще порок нашего времени, очень серьезный  личностной недостаток.)  Мне было бы также интересно послушать ваше мнение на такую тему: почему из трех слов синтаксис только "так что" считает полноценным союзом. Это было бы замечательно, если бы вы сумели ответить на вопрос. Но после ваших слов (начинает нам что-то там  "втирать") я могу предположить, что Его величество синтаксис не захочет с вами иметь никакого дела. И я его пониманию: такое отношение к языку простить нельзя. Спасибо вам за внимание.

Answer (score 0):

Постараюсь объяснить максимально просто и понятно, итак

Если слово "значит" указывает на связь мыслей, то оно обособляется:
*Дождь пошел. Это плохо. **Значит,** я достаю зонт.*;

Если слово "значит" - союз, то запятая ставится (согласно правилам подчинительной связи, придаточное следствия);

Если "значит" - сказуемое, то запятая **не нужна**:
*результат экзамена многое значит*

Comment: Хорошо бы "максимально просто и понятно" понять вопрос, а потом уже объяснять. А если слово "значит" - союз, стоящий вначале предложения, то перед ним уже стоит точка, зачем же ставить еще и запятую? Дождь пошел. Значит я достаю зонт.

Comment: А вы никогда не слышали про то, что союз может быть выражен подлежащим, которое, в свою очередь, бывает безличным, как в первом случае. 
А при чем тут точка и запятая после нее — знаете только вы, ведь изначально про это речи не шло. :)